# Multiple :target style entries into one

Tags: css

I was wondering if there was anyway to make this CSS more compact and generic

```
 #av:target, #bis:target, #ena:target, #esc:target, #kis:target, #kso:target... {
background:red;
}
```

basically I have many of these styles and without code would like if i could just have one entry for all since they all do the same thing.

Comment: How about `*:target`? That selects all: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ids must be unique, your solutions are two: classnames or attributes. Examples:

### With class

```
  <!-- HTML: -->
  <element class="target">

  <!-- CSS: -->
  .target:target { 
      /* your styles **/
  }
```

### With attribute

```
  <!-- HTML: -->
  <element data-target=""> <!-- Can be empty or filled, but the important is the attribute -->

  <!-- CSS: -->
  [data-target]:target { 
      /* your styles **/
  }
```

By this mode, you have one rule in your CSS that you can apply to all elements that you need. Choose the one that best fits with your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for replying so I have links such as
      <li><a href="#kis">Kaspersky Internet Security</a></li>
if i want two different elements to apply different styles too im confused on how i'd achieve that

Comment: `<li><a href="#kis" class="target">Kaspersky Internet Security</a></li>` Simple and clean

Comment: I meant on this part sorry '<tr id="kis">' it needs to be unique for the page scroll but for the style?

Comment: It's the same in all tags: `<tr id="kis" class="target">`. Ids must be unique, but classnames not